# Self join to JSON in Spring Boot rest

Tags: java, jackson

I have an Account object containing a OneToMany relation with Beneficiary object and this relationship is bi-directional so I have a ManyToOne relation in the Beneficiary Object with Account Object

```
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String number;
    //Other fields
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Beneficiary> beneficiaries = new ArrayList<>();
}


public class Beneficiary {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    //Other fields
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Account account;
}
```

In the JSON response, I need the Account information containing the list of Beneficiaries and for each Beneficiary I just need the Account name and Account number. Is it possible to serialize it somehow so that I get response in this fashion? Or do I need to modify my entity structures?
Sample Account Response -

```
{
    "id": 123,
    "name": "Name1",
    "number": "111111",
    "beneficiaries": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "account": {
                "name": "Name2",
                "number": "222222"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "account": {
                "name": "Name3",
                "number": "333333"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to serialize your JPA objects. Instead, you need to define domain objects. These are objects are the ones to be serialize and exposed to the business. This abstraction decouples your REST or SOAP or whatever interface with your JPA layer.

I would create a domain class for your account class. Call it AccountDTO or something like that. Any object being returned from your JPA repositories need to be mapped to this DTO objects and bubbled up to the services layer. Then your DTO is the class which models your business needs. In there you can just put the accounts and the beneficiaries names.

DTO stands for Data Transfer Objects. These are the ones supposed to be serialized and sent between systems.

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use a custom serializer.

You would have to write a custom serializer, similar to this:

```
public class NestedAccountSerializer extends StdSerializer<Account> {

    public NestedAccountSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public NestedAccountSerializer(Class<Account> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Account account, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeObject(new AccountView(account.getName(), account.getNumber()));
    }

    private static class AccountView {
        @JsonProperty
        private final String name;
        @JsonProperty
        private final String number;

        AccountView(String name, String number) {
            this.name = name;
            this.number = number;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this in your `Beneficiary` class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@JsonSerialize(using = NestedAccountSerializer.class)
private Account account;
```

Please, let me know if it helped.